# Problem with virsh commands

Tags: ide, disk, kvm, hotplugging

I have been trying to use virsh attah-disk to attach a qcow2 file as additional storage source. The syntax i am using is (from internet):

```
virsh attach-disk --driver file vm2 disk2.qcow2 hdc
```

If the vm is running or paused it shows:

```
error: this function is not supported by the hypervisor: disk bus 'ide' cannot be hotplugged.
```

If the vm is shutdown it shows:

```
error: Requested operation is not valid: cannot attach device on inactive domain
```

I am not sure about the hdc parameter. I have tried using attach-device function also with xml file as:

```
<disk type="file" device="disk">
    <driver name="file"/>
    <source file="/gfs1/disk2.qcow2"/>
    <target dev="hdc"/>
</disk>
```

But this also shows:

```
error: Failed to attach device from /gfs1/disk2tovm2.xml
error: this function is not supported by the hypervisor: disk bus 'ide' cannot be hotplugged.
```

I looked at many examples but none of them worked and all had almost the same syntax.
If someone could help me figure out the error.

### COMPLETE CONFIGURATION FILE OF VM

```
root@blade1:/vms# virsh dumpxml vm2
<domain type='kvm' id='33'>
  <name>vm2</name>
  <uuid>70affd5d-af95-72c5-2d96-c131f46409b6</uuid>
  <description>--autostart</description>
  <memory>1048576</memory>
  <currentMemory>1048576</currentMemory>
  <vcpu>2</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='i686' machine='pc-0.14'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/vms/vm2.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:5e:98:e4'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <target dev='vnet0'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/0'/>
      <target port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/0'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/0'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='6900' autoport='no' listen='0.0.0.0'/>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='apparmor'>
    <label>libvirt-70affd5d-af95-72c5-2d96-c131f46409b6</label>
    <imagelabel>libvirt-70affd5d-af95-72c5-2d96-c131f46409b6</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
</domain>
```

Comment: Can you post your config for the rest of the VM?  Are you using Virtio?  Also, I think your cdrom is probably configured with hdc.

Comment: I have added complete configuration of vm in the question itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because you are trying to attach the disk to a
running domain using **IDE** architecture.

Imagine you have a real physical server, can you open it up while it is running
and plug in an IDE drive?  No, the architecture does not support it.  KVM/QEMU,
trying to emulate this architecture, must then present the error you are
seeing: "disk bus 'ide' cannot be hotplugged."

One solution is to attach the disk using SCSI archicture.  SCSI supports hot plugging.  The command you would use would be:

virsh attach-disk --driver file vm2 disk2.qcow2 sdc

The only change is "sdc" instead of "hdc".  This hints to KVM/QEMU that you want SCSI instead of IDE, and it will attach the disk.

Also, when the domain is stopped, you can't use attach-disk because this function is meant for running domains.

Answer (score 2):

newbie to this site but just wanted to comment i have succeeded uploading an iso / hot swap an image on virtd.
my command is as follows:

```
virsh attach-disk $srvkvmname /<datastorename>/tsgboot.iso hdb --driver qemu --type cdrom --mode readonly
```

i know that omitting the driver type and on causes the above error.

Comment: It looks different as you are attaching it as a cdrom and not hard disk. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: yes, i am attaching a cdrom but it seems the same way to use if want an HD, changing only the type. i have not tested it so if someone can confirm it would be great.